# need help on trigonometry encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a code that requires me to embed trignometry formula. actually i have the formula but i am confused how to implement that into my code.i am trying to find out everywhere & i am getting too but not getting exactly what i need.the formula is like

```
Axh = Ax cos θz 
Ayh = Ay cos θy

|AI | =sqrt(|Axh|^2 + |Ayh|^2)

α = arccos(Axh/|AI|)
β = arccos(Ayh/|AI |)       

Alat =Axh sin α+ Ayh sin β
```

these are formulas so anyone out there can help me with geometric coding or any simple project from where i can learn.. thanks

Comment: Trigonometric functions are defined in `<math.h>` and automatically included in a default Xcode project, so what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As Saphrosit said the functions are already included here is an example on how to implement a mathematic formula on Objective-C in this case it is the Haversine formula. Just look up for the possible functions on

[Haversine Formula Implementation](http://www.jaimerios.com/?p=39)

Here are some math functions that may prove useful to your purpose:

[Functions](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/objective-c-math-functions/)